# Universal links on iOS application

Tags: swift, ios-universal-links

I know this has been asked before but I have been debugging quite a bit and still unable to get universal links to show.

My AASA file:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "<TEAM_ID>.<BUNDLE_ID>"
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "/dl": "/dl/*"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have the file hosted (with no redirects) at `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` and `/apple-app-site-association/`.

I have tried the website https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool to validate my website and it keeps saying:

```
http://example.com is returning 500. Please check your url and try again.
```

Why is it getting a 500??? My server logs have nothing related to that. I'm using Nginx, uwsgi, and Django if that helps.

Comment: Can you give us the actual URL in question?

Comment: I can't get your site to load via HTTPS (HTTP loads), on either IP address (both 34.212.239.19 and 44.225.194.227 are listed). Looks like you're on AWS; have you permitted the public internet to access your server on port 443?

Comment: That was the issue. thank you. Deleted my previous URL comment.